# What's the type library file correspand to Office VBA Object Library?

Tags: c++, automation, powerpoint

I am using PowerPoint2010 c++ automation,in visual c++ 2010.

The **GradientStops**,it is a object in Office.You can check [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/Office-Shared-VBA/articles/gradientstops-object-office).

I want the C++ automation interfaces for the GradientStops Object, but I can't find the type library file.(like PowerPoint2010 automation, it's a file named "MSPPT.OLB").

So my question is:

How to find the type library file(including GradientStops object)?

Comment: This is something you can reverse-engineer with the Oleview.exe utility, File > View Typelib command.  Select msppt.olb, copy paste the decompiled output from the right pane into a text editor.  You'll see the GradientStops interface being used, but not declared.  Back to the top, note the importlib statements.  VBE6EXT.OLB has definitions for the VB object model, the type library embedded in MSO.DLL has definitions that other Office programs use as well.  That's the one, #import it from the C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\OFFICExx directory.

Comment: @Hans Passant  Thank you，I find the object.